# Error on Heroku while uploading images to mongoDB using Multer

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku, mongoose

I have developed an app where the user can upload images using multer and can retrieve/view them on the home screen. I'm using MongoDB as my database, locally it works perfectly. Even when using MongoDB CL, It's running well locally. But when I deploy it to Heroku with the database connection link, I'm getting the following error.

```
2020-07-06T16:21:38.008989+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=quiet-anchorage-51950.herokuapp.com request_id=146ff967-98bb-45e5-a234-4dbf9535abbe fwd="124.123.143.110" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

**Here is my app.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var multer  = require('multer');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'uploads')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
    }
});
var upload = multer({ storage: storage })

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://<myname>:<removedpassword>@webdatabase.rbrhg.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
```

**The image Schema I have used:**

```
const imgSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    img: {
        data: Buffer,
        contentType: String
    }
});
```

**The post request I made to upload the images:**

```
app.post('/imgupload', upload.single('image'), function (req, res, next) {
    var image = new Image({
        img: {
            data: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname + '/uploads/' + req.file.filename)),
            contentType: 'image/png'
        }
    });
    image.save();
    res.render("app",{Name: req.body.username});
});
```

**Here is my package.json file:**

```
{
  "name": "igwebsite",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.16.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.5.9",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.21",
    "multer": "^1.4.2"
  }
}
```

**The Thing is I want my locally-perfect web app to work online, Can someone please help?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, But I solved it. The problem in my case is the Port value, The OR condition I'm using might be wrong. Maybe it's just taking 3000 and not the port which Heroku provides.

All I did was changed this

```
app.listen(3000 || process.env.PORT,() => {
   console.log("Server is up at port "+process.env.PORT);
});
```

**to this:**

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000,() => {
   console.log("Server is up at port "+process.env.PORT);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store files/images in aws s3
refer this https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-s3